# I want to call a visual c# event within another event. How do I do that?

Tags: c#

I want to call `btnDisconnect_Click` within `btnExit_Click`.

```
private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //does something
}

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //I want to call btnDisconnect_Click. What line of code should I use here?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually in cases like these I make my click handlers only call another function and pass in appropriate arguments:

```
private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DoDisconnect();
}

private void DoDisconnect()
{
   ...
}
```

Then I can call that same function from wherever:

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DoDisconnect();
}
```

This way your "disconnect" logic is gummed up by taking dummy arguments that don't actually affect the disconnect behavior in any way.

It also means you can start factoring out view logic from forms.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on if you are using the arguments passed to the event handlers

You could yust call it using `nulls`

Something like

```
private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   //does something 
} 

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   //I want to call btnDisconnect_Click. What line of code should I use here? 
   btnDisconnect_Click(null,null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They're just methods. Just call it. You'll need to provide whatever event arguments btnDisconnect_Click is expecting (which is probably nothing). So the simplest thing is:

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnDisconnect_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

This will pass the current form/window/whatever it is as the sender, and an EventArgs object with no data.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it just as you have it listed. The `this` below isn't necessary but it puts context on the code:

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //I want to call btnDisconnect_Click. What line of code should I use here?
   this.btnDisconnect_Click(null, null);

   // If you need to have sender as something you can always put
   // this in directly
   this.btnDisconnect_Click(this.btnDisconnect, new System.EventArgs());
}
```

Comment: @jgauffin - that would work too. I put in the `new` on the assumption that using that line OP would to be doing something special. My preference (if it's this simple) is to pass null. If it's not this simple, my preference is to use something along the lines of the refactors listed in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption here and say that what you're trying to do is call a Disconnect (perhaps a network resource) for both the disconnect and exit buttons.  Instead of calling one event handler method from the other you may want to refactor the disconnect event handler's code into a separate method.  Then call that method from both handlers.  For example:

```
private void Disconnect()
{
    //Disconnect here
}

private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do some other stuff here
    Disconnect();
}

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do some other exit stuff here
    Disconnect();
}
```

This makes your code much cleaner and saves you from having to call one event handler from another.  This begins to separate your view logic from the rest of your program's logic, which is much more desirable and much easier to maintain in the long run.  For instance you may want a separate controller for handling the network resource, instead of embedding it into the view's logic.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case you can just call the btnDiconnect_Click directly as follows:

```
private void btnDisconnct_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Does Something
}

private void btnExit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Call btnDisconnect_Click()
    btnDisconnect_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just call the method passing in valid parameters.

```
btnDisconnect_Click(btnDisconnect,new EventArgs());
```

However you might want to consider refactoring out the code in `btnDisconnect` into a new method and calling that instead:

```
private void doSomething()
{
   //....
}

private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   doSomething();
} 

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{// this is probably your constructor
.
    public delegate void MyCustomHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
.
    MyCustomHandler myCustomHandler = new MyCustomHandler(); //you can do more in your delegates constructor, members etc

    myCustomHandler += btnExit_Click;
    myCustomHandler += btnDisconnect_Click;
}

private void btnDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   // do Something
} 

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do Something
}





//And wherever you need to invoke these, you do
myCustomHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```